# How to set fixed size of a terminal window?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am writing a program, using ncurses, that outputs a very wide table. I would not like to cut off or wrap the table when the terminal window is to small. Is there any possibility to force the scroll bars to appear when the window is to small, or can I set a fixed size of a terminal window and disable changing its size by a user?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

**EDIT:** I use Linux/Ubuntu and gnome-terminal.

Comment: I could be wrong but last I checked this was an OS thing not an Ncurses thing. Ncurses is for the UI you display in the terminal, not for controlling the aspects of the terminal itself.

Comment: Can you let us know what operating system (Windows/macOS/Linux) and what terminal you are using?

Comment: @fleix I use Linux/Ubuntu and gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "pad" demo in the "ncurses" program in ncurses' "test" folder. It's a pretty smooth implementation of a scrollable window implemented *within* curses. That's the route I'd suggest.

But, there *are* escape sequences to resize *some* terminals, including gnome-terminal. Note, there are no curses functions to generate these sequences. Doing this takes you outside the realm of curses. For example: [Xterm terminal and resize code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709581/xterm-terminal-and-resize-code)